# when to use L.TileLayer vs L.tileLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have just been using Leaflet to build a map for a website and noticed that to add a Tile Layer at least two methods can be used, `L.TileLayer()` and `L.tileLayer()`, differing in their name only by the case of a single character.

However, while the object returned by both of these methods can be added to a map object returned by `L.map()` the object returned by `L.TileLayer()` does not seem to have the `addTo()` method whilst the object returned by`L.tileLayer()`. E.g. both

```
var map = L.map('map');
var tiles = new L.TileLayer(<tileUrl>, {attribution: <tileAttrib>});
map.addLayer(tiles);
```

and

```
var map = L.map('map');
var tiles = new L.tileLayer(<tileUrl>, {attribution: <tileAttrib>});
map.addLayer(tiles);
```

as well as

```
var map = L.map('map');
L.tileLayer(<tileUrl>, {attribution: <tileAttrib>}).addTo(map);
```

whilst

```
var map = L.map('map');
L.TileLayer(<tileUrl>, {attribution: <tileAttrib>}).addTo(map);
```

fails. Browsing the documentation of Leaflet it seems the proper method to use is `L.tileLayer()` so the question then is what is the use of `L.TileLayer()`?

Here's a full example of my code so far, to try the different alternatives simply uncomment the one to test and make sure the others are commented

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ=="
            crossorigin=""/>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q=="
            crossorigin=""> </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="makeMap()">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function makeMap() {
            var tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
            var tileAttrib = 'Map data &copy <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'; 
            var map = L.map('map').setView([63,15],9);
            
            // using tileLayer and addLayer - this works
            var tiles = new L.tileLayer(tileUrl, {attribution: tileAttrib});
            map.addLayer(tiles);
            
            // using tileLayer and addTo - this works
//             L.tileLayer(tileUrl, {attribution: tileAttrib}).addTo(map);
            
            // using TileLayer and addLayer - this works
//             var tiles = new L.TileLayer(tileUrl, {attribution: tileAttrib});
//             map.addLayer(tiles);
            
            // using TileLayer and addTo - this fails
//             L.TileLayer(tileUrl, {attribution: tileAttrib}).addTo(map);
         }
         
      </script>
      <table border=1 style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
         <tr style="height: 100%;">
            <td>
               <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L267  vs  https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L39

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

These two are both valid and equivalent:

```
var foo = L.tileLayer(arguments);
var foo = new L.TileLayer(arguments);
```

These two are syntactically valid (because of Javascript's historical baggage) but will ultimately result in errors:

```
var foo = new L.tileLayer(arguments);
var foo = L.TileLayer(arguments);
```

---

> to add a tilelayer at least two methods can be used, `L.TileLayer()` and `L.tileLayer()`

Well, they're not really two *methods*. Technically `L.TileLayer` is an instance of `Object`, and `L.tileLayer` is an instance of `Function`, which inherits the prototype of `Object`. And `L` acts as a namespace rather than a class instance.

You see, Object-Oriented Programming in Javascript is *weird*. You can use the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) with pretty much any object which has a prototype. And [prototype-based inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) is confusing to grasp to most people versed in "proper" OOP.

Nowadays, with the ES2015 standards and the fancy `class` keywords this is not really a problem (I'd say it's a problem, but hidden under layers of syntactic sugar). But back in the day, developers had to resort to, let's say, [creative solutions for class inheritance](https://johnresig.com/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) which sometimes involves [messing with the prototype chain](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/hooray/).

Leaflet uses a combination of such methods - and *as an undesired side effect*, `L.TileLayer` becomes a `Function` and one can call `L.TileLayer()` directly and that's quite confusing.

Leaflet also uses the concept of [*factory functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29): A function that returns an instance of a class. Quoting from [one of the Leaflet tutorials](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html):

> Most Leaflet classes have a corresponding [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29). A factory function has the same name as the class, but in `lowerCamelCase` instead of `UpperCamelCase`:
>
> ```
> function myBoxClass(name, options) {
>     return new MyBoxClass(name, options);
> }
> ```

This is meant just as a convenience: it saves the user from typing the `new` keyword back in an era where the `new` keyword was *feared*.

But this creates *another undesired side effect*, because in Javascript all `Function`s have a prototype, which means that you can do stuff like

```
 function myFunction() { ... }
 var wtf = new myFunction();
```

Therefore, `new L.tileLayer()` is also valid syntax (but fails at runtime).

---

> then what is the use of `L.TileLayer()`?

Once again, `L.TileLayer()` as a function call is an undesired side effect. But `L.TileLayer` represents a class and it's important to have a reference to that, because of things like:

```
 if (layer instanceof L.TileLayer)
```